# Meson+Vala: what if C file depends on the package header generated by --header flag

Tags: vala, meson-build

I want to do something like this:

```
project('pro', 'vala', 'c')
executable(meson.project_name(),
    'foo.vala'
    'bar.c')
```

where `bar.c` depends on types defined in `foo.vala`. If I did it by hand I would first call vala compiler with `--header foo.h` flag and then compile everything by a C compiler.

But what I actually see in meson's build process is that `bar.c` gets compiled before `foo.vala` and vala compiler gets invoked with no --header flag. So build fails. Adding `vala_header: 'foo.h'` doesn't help.

How do I do it properly?

Comment: You could try building foo.vala as a library